# Separate text in excel cell based on formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to split text in one cell to 2 cells based on the formatting of the content in the cell. In the image below: I would like to separate the text in blue from the email address. Could anyone suggest an excel formula or workaround to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works, however I don't know your font color codes, so in my example I'm using red.  You will need to figure out the font colors in your cells.

Use `MsgBox ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.Color` to get the code for the first character in the `ActiveCell`.

The way it works is it check each character in the string 1 at a time.  If the character is red, then it adds a digit to the `c` variable. At the end I take the left `c` number of characters.

```
Sub test1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim l As Integer


While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

i = 1
c = 0
l = Len(ActiveCell.Value)

While i <= l

If ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=i).Font.Color = 255 Then
c = c + 1
i = i + 1

Else

i = i + 1

End If

Wend

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(ActiveCell.Value, c)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Right(ActiveCell.Value, l - c)

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Wend

End Sub
```

Results in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Alt + F11 to open the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window
2. Past the following code:

   ```
   Function GetBoldString(workCell As Range)  
   strLen = Len(workCell)  
   GetBoldString = ""  
   For i = 1 To strLen  
      If workCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Then  
          GetBoldString = GetBoldString & workCell.Characters(i, 1).Text  
      End If  
   Next i  
   End Function  

   Function GetNoBoldString(workCell As Range)  
   strLen = Len(workCell)  
   GetNoBoldString = ""  
   For i = 1 To strLen  
      If workCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = False Then  
         GetNoBoldString = GetNoBoldString & workCell.Characters(i, 1).Text  
   End If  
   Next i  
   End Function
   ```
3. Return to the spreadsheet.
   In the cell where you want the bold part paste:

   = GetBoldString(A1)
4. In the cell where you want the no bold part paste:

   = GetNoBoldString(A1)

Replace A1 with the reference to cell you want to split.

Working on the properties of workCell.Characters(i, 1) you can split by other format attributes, like color.

Here are two VBA functions to separate the string part of any color, different from black, from the black part.

```
Function GetColorString(workCell As Range)
strLen = Len(workCell)
GetColorString = ""
For i = 1 To strLen
    If workCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color <> vbBlack Then
        GetColorString = GetColorString & workCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
    End If
Next i
End Function

Function GetBlackString(workCell As Range)
strLen = Len(workCell)
GetBlackString = ""
For i = 1 To strLen
    If workCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack Then
        GetBlackString = GetBlackString & workCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
End If
Next i
End Function
```

[image: Here is the result using this VBA functions:]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to seperate the blue text from the other with as sample a semicolon? Because then you could split the string which include the value of the cell: `StrArray = Split(CellXY.Value, ";")` strArray is a string array which get the two elements "Arnald, Biarb" and "dfgh.sukusi@drems.com". Then you just have to say which cell should get which value. As sample: `CellXY.Value = strArray(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch

I built this based on your vba and it can now separate different colors and run the whole column. Hope it helps everyone.

```
Sub SplitCellBasedOnColor()

Dim Cel As Range
For Each Cel In Application.Selection.Cells

i = 1
Group = 1
wholelength = Len(Cel.Value)
GroupOrder = 1
CellOrder = 1

'''loop to separate each group of text within same color
While i < wholelength
If Cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color = _
    Cel.Characters(Start:=i + 1, Length:=1).Font.Color Then
Group = Group + 1
i = i + 1
Else
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).NumberFormat = "@"
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).Value = Mid(Cel, GroupOrder, Group)
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).Font.Color = Cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color
GroupOrder = GroupOrder + Group
Group = 1
i = i + 1
CellOrder = CellOrder + 1
End If
Wend


'''when i = wholelength then run below
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).NumberFormat = "@"
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).Value = Mid(Cel, GroupOrder, Group)
Cel.Offset(0, CellOrder).Font.Color = Cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color

'''cell in next row
Next Cel

End Sub
```

Result as follows:

[image]